# When using Virtual Documents how can a template be used with different report parameters?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm using a virtual document structure generated by a script to create a document from EA, and I'm trying to use the same template fragment several times with different elements and different headings.

For example, I have an element which describes the input data to one program, and the output data to another program, so I can't really store the information in the element I'm documenting.

Where it is the input, I want one  heading (and similar references within the template), and where it is output I want different values for the headings.

I've tried using the `ReportTitle` tagged value in the individual `<model document>` element, but this appears to be ignored and only the `<report package>` value is used throughout (which makes me wonder why they are there in the first place).

While I could create multiple templates all referring to the same fragment and hard-code the different headings, but that is messy, and as I already have fragments within fragments so it could result in a lot of almost identical templates and fragments. Variables that I can set for each `<model document>` would be much preferable.

Has anyone got a better approach than this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy solution.

If there is a way to determine based on the element, package, or diagram ID whether you should use one title or the other then you could use a script or SQL fragment to return the correct title.

If that is not the case I guess the only possibility is to hardcode the different titles in your templates.
In order to avoid too much duplication you could create a template with only the title and use that on a model document. Since you are generating the modeldocuments by a script anyway that doesn't cost any user time.

Comment: I've created a set of "header" elements so that each header template can be referred to a single element, rather than having specific header templates, which is easy enough given the virtual document is scripted. I may even enhance the script to depend on these header elements in a package for each document type.